# VBA macro to Copy a SQL error code into Excel

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, macros

I am trying to write/adopt a macro in VBA to copy a SQL query into Excel.
I have it connecting and executing. When I run it manually in SQL, this is the error code in SQL:

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#MSP_History3', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

(8661 row(s) affected)
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#MSP1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

(8661 row(s) affected)
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#MSP_PBP', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

(8661 row(s) affected)
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table 'dbo.MSP_History', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Looks like its not a great query, but what interests me is the number of rows affected.

Here is the latter portion of the VBA code that someone more skilled than me had  used for a different query that works to paste the table result in A1:

```
'Open the connection.
cn.Open strConn
'
'Set and Execute SQL Command
Set cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd1.CommandText = SQLquery
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd1.Execute

'Open Recordset
Set rs1.ActiveConnection = cn
rs1.Open cmd1

'Paste Column Headers into Spreadsheet
    For Col = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
    Range("A1").Offset(0, Col).Value = rs1.Fields(Col).Name
    Next

'Copy Data to Excel
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

This code works for a properly-executed SQL query. Is there a way to copy the error message?

Ideally what I want in cell A1 in Excel is just "8661".

Thanks!

edit: Currently the error message in VBA upon executing the "cmd1.Execute" line is:

```
Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Automation error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with this code... It shows the error on a message box.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Connect()

On Error GoTo InvalidValue:

Dim myCn As MyServer
Set myCn = New MyServer

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "Select * from myTable", myCn.GetConnection

Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
myCn.Shutdown

Set rs = Nothing
Set myCn = Nothing

Exit Sub

InvalidValue:

MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great!
the error code shows just the second line of the SQL error code : "-2147217865 Cannot drop the table '#MSP_History3', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

Any ideas on how to get the rest of it, or the next line? Number of rows affected is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your welcome! Glad it was useful for you! It seems like you don't have enough permission to execute that query... Have you tried to log in with another user?

Comment: I don't know... I can't help you more... I found this code once and I thought it could be useful for you...

Comment: Check this one.... maybe it works for you! [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676747/how-to-get-the-affected-rows-in-vba-ado-execute)