# Increase speed of multiple inserts into Access DB from VBA Dictionary

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, adodb

I am attempting to take a VBA Dictionary and either:

- Insert a new row into the database if it does not exist
- Update the row if it does

While my current code works for this, it runs extremely slowly for the thousands of records I may need to update, and other solutions I have found on this site do not really achieve what I am after. Could anyone help me achieve this? My code so far is below:

```
Sub UpdateDatabase(dict As Object)
Dim Conn As Object, StrSQL As String, Rs As Object
Dim hmm As ADODB.Recordset

Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
Conn.Open "C:\XXXX\cfrv2.accdb" 

dictCount = dict.Count
counter = 0
For Each varKey In dict.Keys()
    Application.StatusBar = Str(counter) & "/" & Str(dictCount)
    counter = counter + 1
    StrSQL = "SELECT * FROM `All SAMs Backlog` WHERE [LOCID] = '" & varKey & "'"

    Set hmm = Conn.Execute(StrSQL)
    If hmm.BOF And hmm.EOF Then
        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO `ALL SAMs Backlog` ([SAM], [LOCID], [RTC Date], [CFR Status], [CFR Completed Date], [CFR On Hold Reason], [MDU], [ICWB Issue], [Obsolete]) VALUES (dict.Item(varKey)(0), '" & varKey & "', '20/12/2018', '" & dict.Item(varKey)(1) & "', '02/01/2019', '" & dict.Item(varKey)(2) & "' , '" & dict.Item(varKey)(3) & "' , '" &dict.Item(varKey)(4) & "' , '" & dict.Item(varKey)(5) & "')"
        Conn.Execute (StrSQL)
    Else
        'Update the LOC in the table
        StrSQL = "UPDATE `All SAMs Backlog` SET ([CFR Status] = '" & dict.Item(varKey)(1) & "', [CFR On Hold Reason] = '" & dict.Item(varKey)(2) & "', [MDU] = '" & dict.Item(varKey)(3) & "', [ICWB Issue] = '" & dict.Item(varKey)(4) & "', [Obsolete] = '" & dict.Item(varKey)(5) & "')"
        Conn.Execute (StrSQL)
    End If
Next

Conn.Close
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Depending on how many inserts vs updates you have, you could first run the update and check on the "records affected" value, then if that's zero run the insert.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676747/how-to-get-the-affected-rows-in-vba-ado-execute

Comment: I am surprised code works. Should use `[ ]` to delimit table and field names, not apostrophes: `[All SAMs Backlog]`. If the LocID is common key, can't you join tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upserting in MS-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

Write the content of the dictionary to a temp table, then run a query as described here:

[Update or insert data in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table/29272782#29272782)

or:

Open `[All SAMs Backlog]` as a recordset, loop the dictionary to *add* or *edit* records as needed, then close the recordset.